# The property 'kids' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: flutter, list, dart

I have two models 'Kindergarten' and 'Kid'. I also have GetX controller where I store kindergarten informations who has information about lists of kids.

I want to if 'kids' list is empty to show widget with text 'Empty list', but when I use if-else statement it says 'The property 'kids' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.'

I tried to check for currentKindergarten if it's empty then check for kids list if it is empty but issue remains.

```
if (_kindergartenController.currentKindergarten ==
                            null) {
                          return Container(
                            child: Text("Error"),
                          );
                        } else {
                          if (_kindergartenController
                                  .currentKindergarten.kids ==
                              null) {
                            return Container(
                              child: Text('Empty list'),
                            );
                          } else {
                            return DataTable2(), }
```

Controller looks like this and currentKindergarten has property of List? beacuse list its self can be null

```
class KindergartenController extends GetxController {
  KindergartenModel? currentKindergarten = KindergartenModel();
}
```

I want to show lists of kids inside the table and if the list is empty to represent it with text in container widget.

Comment: Since `_kindergartenController.currentKindergarten` can be null (observe that you put a ? when you declared it) you cannot access its kids (cos it might be null). You need to check whether currentKindergarten is null first (or use a null-aware short hand). Such a shorthand would be `_kindergartenController.currentKindergarten?.kids`

Comment: https://dart.dev/codelabs/dart-cheatsheet#null-aware-operators

Comment: Yes but didn’t I check it before in if-else statement? I mean it’s kind a dumb that I still have put operator for it even tho I checked for if it is null or it isn’t

Comment: That only works for local variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a current limitation of the Dart language. You can read more about it in related GitHub issues:

- https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1187
- https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/104

A way around your problem is using a local variable for null checks. For example:

```
final kinderGarten = _kindergartenController.currentKindergarten;
if (kinderGarten == null) {
  //
} else {
  // Do any operations on kinderGarten.kids 
  // kinderGarten is guaranteed to be not null
}
```